# How do I add something to my html using javascript without erasing the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have a small calculator that I'm adding to my html. It has a few dropdowns to select stuff and when a person hits a submit button, I'd like to display a picture below the calculator in my html. I've tried using a javascript function with: document.write() but that clears the whole page. Is there a way that I can get a javascript function to run which only adds a picture to my page when a submit button is clicked?

Here's a BASIC outline of my code with the part I'm having trouble with:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function calc_rate() {

    //code that displays a message after the submit button is hit        
    document.write("answer");
}

</script>

</head>
<body>


<table>


<tr>
    <td class=rate_calc_label>Select Your Option Type:</td>
<td><select name="type1">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>  


<tr>
<td class=rate_calc_label>Select The Second Number:</td>
<td><select name="type2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="calc_button" onclick="calc_rate()"/></td>
<td></td>
</tr>    

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

would it be possible to use some kind of inner-HTML? That's what I got from others on stockoverflow but I'm still a little confused

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a placeholder element for your output. Then set the innerHTML for that element:

```
<div id='answer'></div>
```

then:

```
document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "answer is:" + yourdata
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I was able to make an empty div like you said and then add code for a picture to go in there.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use document.write, period. Use DOM operations: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Comment: This answer would be better if it provided some details here, rather than just a link to a very long document.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `document.write()` you can set the `innerHTML` property of any DOM node to add text to the page.

Say you add a `<div id='result'></div>` to the end of the page (before the body tag). Then in your javascript have:

```
var result_display = document.getElementById('result');
// and in calc_rate():
result_display.innerHTML = "answer";
```

Note that this will always reset the result_display's text. You can also wrap that operation in a function:

```
function displayResult(result){
    result_display.innerHTML = '<h2>' + result + '</h2>'; // or whatever formatting
}
```