# How to make a function for: document.write(" ")

Tags: javascript, function, document.write

Hi I want to shorten this: `document.write("")`.

Instead i made my function:

```
function myFunc() {
    document.write()
}
```

and I want that ill be able to modify it like this: `myFunc("hello world")`
 but it did not work.

Comment: the reson why I wanted to do this so I shouldnt have to write out the whole thing (document.write)

Comment: Aside from not having any arguments, how did your function "not work"?

Comment: Thats one of the very strange question I have come across!

Comment: because i didnt see it say foo or hello... on the webpage

Comment: Looking at your snippet, it seems that you forgot to use a param to pass the text to the `document.write()` function, is that right?

Comment: never mind! just tell me if that is the correct way how to do it, if it not then please tell me!

Comment: Anyway, if it was my function and I want to shorten its name you would surely use `dw()`, but its your call...

Comment: Notice, that you can use your function at parsing time only. If it's called after a page has been parsed, it'll wipe out all the code on the page and create a new document.

Comment: If you want to learn how functions work, I recommend to [read a tutorial about functions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to take an argument. Right now, you're trying to pass it one, but it doesn't take any, then you call `document.write()` with no arguments, so it doesn't write anything. You can add a parameter like this:

```
function myFunc(s)
{
    document.write(s);
}
```

Comment: ok, so lets say I want a function and when ever I call it I want to specify the string  (what i want it to say on the web) with the parameters..

Comment: like this: myFunc(hello world) - it should show on page "hello world"

Comment: @mendel goldstein Guess you could try `myFunc("hello world");` ... but to you question 'how do I do it?' ... Do what?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dave I'm trying to create an output for my js on the webpage instead of using the alert function

Comment: If this is for debugging, you may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539253/what-is-console-log.  If not for debugging purpose, you can use DOM methods to insert or update element content dynamically, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907053/how-do-i-add-something-to-my-html-using-javascript-without-erasing-the-whole-pag